# Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. The following dependencies on the compile classpath?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-room, androidx

I am developing new app using android architecture components but I am getting the following error from gradle

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>     - lifecycle-compiler-2.0.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0)
>   Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>   See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for

below is my app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lifecycleawaredemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'

    def lifecyle_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecyle_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecyle_version"
}
```

below my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you appear to be mixing up your androidx lifecycle dependencies. You are using androidx artifacts, so you can drop this part:

```
def lifecyle_version = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecyle_version"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecyle_version"
```

You should only need:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
```

Now, as to the error, the message says that the lifecycle-compiler contains annotation processors, so you should add them to the annotationProcessor configuration. To do this, add the following line at the apply plugin section for your app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

This will enable the kotlin annotation processor support. Next, change the:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
```

to allow the compiler to use the included annotation processors:

```
kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
```

and that should compile fine.